# Composite component does not print #{cc.attrs.xxx} in style attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, attributes, facelets, composite-component

I am observing this component snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
  <cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="width" default="300"/>
    <cc:attribute name="height" default="400"/>
  </cc:interface>
  <cc:implementation>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="styles.css"/>
    <h:form prependId="false">
      <div id="links" style="width: #{cc.attrs.width}px; height: #{cc.attrs.height}px">              
        </ul>
      </div>          
    </h:form>
  </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

*p.s.the code is modified*

...[which shows](http://mrbool.com/customizing-components-in-jsf-2-0/23854) how to set css values dynamically; I tried the way with css as :

`style="width: #{cc.attrs.width}px; height: #{cc.attrs.height}px"`

**EDIT**

I tried to use the component (in same project) as a simple tag placing it to *"WEB-INF/mytestcomponent"* :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
   <namespace>http://testcomponent.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
   <tag>
    <tag-name>testComponent</tag-name>
      <source>testComponent.xhtml</source>      
   </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

p.s.according to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/) example

Then I call the component as :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:test="http://testcomponent.com/jsf/facelets"
      >

<body>
...
<test:testComponent></test:testComponent>
...
</body>
</html>
```

but seems like it doesn't work :( The generated code gives empty values as

```
"width: ; height:"
```

So my question is what causes the issue and how to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: How did you call your component? I tested your code and it works well for me

Comment: @tfosra I edited my question please watch it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how a composite component should be declared. Just take a look at SO [composite-component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info)  tag info

This is what is says (I have simplified it for your case) :

First create a directory `resources` in the public webcontent (there where the `WEB-INF` directory and all regular Facelets files also are).

```
WebContent
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- lib
 |-- resources   <---
 `-- test.xhtml
```

In the resources directory, create a directory exclusively for composite components. The directory name ends up as the extra path in the composite component namespace URI. You're free to choose the name. We'll take `mycomponents` as an example.

```
WebContent
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- lib
 |-- resources
 |    `-- mycomponents   <---
 `-- test.xhtml
```

This way the composite components in this directory are available in all templates by the following namespace:

```xml
<html xmlns:my="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomponents">
```

The prefix `my` is free to your choice. The `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/` part is mandatory. The `mycomponents` part should be just the same as the directory name.

Now you need to create a new XHTML file and paste your **snippet code** inside it. The filename becomes the composite component tag name. You're free to choose the name. Let's call it `mytestcomponent.xhtml`.

```
WebContent
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- lib
 |-- resources
 |    `-- mycomponents
 |         `-- mytestcomponent.xhtml   <---
 `-- test.xhtml
```

This way the composite component is available in all templates as follows:

```xml
<my:mytestcomponent />
```

Calling it without `width` and `height` attributes will make it use the default values. You can still set these values while calling your CC like this

```xml
<my:mytestcomponent width="500" height="140"/>
```

#### Notes

- The composite component XML declaration tags are available under the namespace `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite`. Before JSF 2.2, the namespace `http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite` should be used instead.

#### Unrelated

- There is an error in your snippet code, It think you should remove an extra `</ul>` there
- `<h:form>` tag should not be embedded into your cc implementation code. You should rather see a cc as a form custom element

Comment: The WEB-INF subfolder must be called "resources" or it can be any name?

Comment: the `resources` folder is placed near `WEB-INF` **not** inside it and it should be named like that. I've edited my answer with more details

Comment: Where the *.taglib.xml must be located ?

Comment: You are not getting it, composite-components and taglibs are different. And the snippet code you wrote is one of a composite-component.

Comment: You mean there is no need to wrap component into tag facelet-taglib? So how you define the namespace as "http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomponents"? I mean should there be a configuration?

Comment: I mean I'd like to define namespace or there is no way to do so?

Comment: It is automatic. As soon as you create the `resources > mycomponents` folder, the name space `xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/mycomponents` will be available. Just read the content of the link I share in my answer

Comment: I just watched the example which shows how to use taglib.xml http://jdevelopment.nl/passing-action-methods-facelets-tags/ the <source> tag - comment please

Comment: I am not sure what tag should be the upper one <ui:component> or <ui:composition>?

Comment: OK I got it concerning the resources folder; Thanks